# POST with curl without sending data

Tags: curl

Is there a way to use curl to send a POST request without sending any data?

We usually post like:

```
curl --data @C:\mydata.txt http://1.2.3.4/myapi
```

If you omit the `--data` you are doing a GET.  How can you omit it and still do a POST?

Comment: Warning, on Microsoft Windows, curl does not seem to work correctly under Power Shell, but does seem to work correctly under Command Prompt.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Randomly found the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84619/how-do-i-make-a-post-request-with-curl/85455#85455) on another post:

`curl -X POST http://example.com`

Comment: Nice. I'm in this situation as well, but it feels a bit odd. I'm wondering if it would be more appropriate to change the call to a GET. I know this is a few years old by now, but any thoughts on that?

Comment: In my case I had to use --data "" otherwise I would get a 411: curl -X POST --data "" url

Comment: @KyleClegg The call should be a POST if it is designed to change something, and might give a different result every time it is called. Not sending data does not mean it won't change something. So in that case it would not be appropriate to change the call into a GET.

Answer (score 17):

Another option is sending a request with empty body, like so:

```
curl http://example.com -d {}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit of a hack, but you could always provide an empty --data file.

Alternately

```
cat /dev/null | curl --data @- http://...
```

Answer (score 2):

In case of libcurl with PHP:

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to be authenticated then below is the command:

```
curl -X POST -u username:password http://example.com
```